# Switch JPanels using layered panel?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

First of all Im a newbie designing with netbeans :)

I created a layered panel and added two jpanels to it.
I want to add a jbutton in one to go to the other panel.

My **aim** is to load a panel when a button is clicked
Is it possible in actionlistner of the jbutton?

lot of posts mentioned card layout. however it is very complex for a newbie like me. If a simple tutorials exists please do mention, if my aim is hard to implement.

Comment: are you looking for a tab panel?

Comment: No I want it to appear as if a fresh frame was loaded
any possible way?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "layered panel"?

Comment: Its a swing component in net beans
it can hold other j panels
i donot know to fully explain because i m a newbie

Comment: Well try this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349137/1057230) for CardLayout, hopefully this might can help a bit :-)

Comment: Did you mean 'Layered Panes'? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Comment: Another option you could do is to set the visible property to false in the on click function for the first panel and set the one you would like to display to true.