# How can i move one frame to another in MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances, mouselistener

I want to `dispose()` my current `jFrame` and move to the next jFrame(StudentProfilepage()).But it shows error at `this.dispose()`.

How can i do that.Here i used `MouseListner` a `jLabel l1`

My code as follows

```
 l1.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());

        l1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            //added check for MouseEvent.BUTTON1 which is left click
            if (e.isPopupTrigger() || e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {

                this.dispose();   //error here(i want to close my current frame and move to StudentProfile() page 

                new StudentProfilePage().setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your class name ?

Comment: Please have a look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), this suites better in this given situation. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349137/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in

```
this.dispose();
```

refers to the `MouseAdapter`, hence the compilation errors you are seeing.

You need to invoke dispose on the `JFrame`

```
JFrameClassName.this.dispose();
```

Also consider using a `JDialog` rather than a `JFrame` as the second window. Read [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

You should write

```
YourClassName.this.dispose();
```

which points to your `jframe`.