# Cannot Clear JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, removeall

I am writing a program where there is a JFrame with a JPanel with a login gui. After logging in successfully, a method is called that clears the JFrame. The issue I am having is that instead of clearing the JFrame, the stuff in the JPanel is still visibly there and it is just frozen.

Method that creates login gui:

```
public void logingui() {

    JPanel loginpanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    JLabel gamename = new JLabel("InvestGame By Ama291");
    gamename.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 22));
    loginpanel.add(gamename, c);
    c.ipady = 20;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    loginpanel.add(new JPanel(), c);
    c.ipady = 10;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;        
    loginpanel.add(new JLabel("Username: "), c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    final JTextField userfield = new JTextField(10);
    loginpanel.add(userfield, c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    loginpanel.add(new JPanel(), c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    loginpanel.add(new JLabel("Password: "), c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    final JPasswordField passfield = new JPasswordField(10);
    loginpanel.add(passfield, c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.ipady = 20;
    loginpanel.add(new JPanel(), c);
    c.ipady = 10;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 6;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    JButton createacc = new JButton("Create Account");
    loginpanel.add(createacc, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    JButton login = new JButton("Log In");
    loginpanel.add(login, c);
    add(loginpanel);
}
```

Method to clear JFrame:

```
public void gamegui() {

    JPanel gamepanel = new JPanel();
    removeAll();
    invalidate();
    validate();
    repaint();
    add(gamepanel);
}
```

Does anyone know how I can successfully remove the JPanel from the JFrame without the buttons and stuff from the JPanel frozen inside of the window? This is the issue I'm having.

Comment: Please consider CardLayout, for this sort of a problem, as already stated. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349137/1057230) :-)

Comment: Going to use CardLayout for something else in my program, thanks for showing me how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a login it is probably better to use a popup JDialog. Then when the dialog closes you just display the panel on the frame.

The other option is to use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). The you can swap panels as required.

Comment: I'm going to try to use a JDialog, it'll make things much easier. I don't have much experience with swing and didn't even know it existed. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Comment: Ok, so I actually fixed my problem by doing setVisible(false); before the removal of the old JPanel and the addition of the new JPanel. Then I set the visibility to true after this was done and it works fine now. However, I decided that I am going to use a JDialog because it basically will have the same function and seems easier to me.

Answer (score 1):

When removing components from a JFrame, the component will be removed but it will visually still be there. Therefore, to hide it or refresh the JFrame, use the .setVisible(false) method.

Comment: Hello my friend! Yeah this is the solution I was looking for but you answered it a bit too late, I'm no longer working on this project

Comment: Fail, didn't check the date

Answer (score 0):

if you ll just add

```
this.setLayout(your layout)
```

//your layout=the layout which you are using. i.e border,card etc..

between the invalidate() and validate() methods in your code in gamegui().

I hope it ll work . I havent tried but hope it ll work.