# JFrame displaying empty panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I decided to try and separate my JWindow from my main menu's JPanel, except now the JPanel is not displaying. When/if I try to call my JWindow class (mainWindow) to add the panel to it, I have to click the button twice as the first time it simply creates an empty JWindow. I simply want it to switch out the panels.
 Any ideas on how I can get the desired effect for my button ?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my main menu panel class :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Database{
    JComponent DatabasePanel() throws IOException {

        // GridBagLayout/Constraint
        GridBagConstraints gridbagcons= new GridBagConstraints();
        gridbagcons.insets = new Insets(15,15,15,15);


        //final String name = window.getName();

        final JComponent window = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("res/FinalBG.png")))); 
        window .setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("res/PlayGame.png"));
        JButton button = new JButton ("", new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));

        //Play Game button Action Listener

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try{

                    panel.setVisible(false);
                    Database = new Database ();
                    JComponent Database = Databasepanel.Database ();
                    Database.setVisible(true);

                    }   catch(IOException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        BufferedImage buttonIcon2 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Scoreboard.png"));
        JButton buttonTwo = new JButton ("", new ImageIcon(buttonIcon2));

        BufferedImage buttonIcon3 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Instructions.png"));
        JButton buttonThree = new JButton ("",new ImageIcon(buttonIcon3));

        // Instructions button ActionListener
        buttonThree.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                }

                });

        BufferedImage buttonIcon1b = ImageIO.read(new File("res/PlayGameHigh.png"));
        button.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon1b));

        BufferedImage buttonIcon2b = ImageIO.read(new File("res/ScoreboardHigh.png"));
        buttonTwo.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon2b));

        BufferedImage buttonIcon3b = ImageIO.read(new File("res/InstructionsHigh.png"));
        buttonThree.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon3b));

        // Setting up GridBagConstraints for each JButton
        gridbagcons.weightx=1;
        gridbagcons.weighty=0;
        gridbagcons.gridx=0;
        gridbagcons.gridy=0;
        gridbagcons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        panel.add(button, gridbagcons); //PLAY GAME

        gridbagcons.weightx=1;
        gridbagcons.weighty=0;
        gridbagcons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gridbagcons.gridx=0;
        gridbagcons.gridy=1;

        panel.add(buttonTwo,gridbagcons); //SCOREBOARD

        gridbagcons.weightx=1;
        gridbagcons.weighty=0;
        gridbagcons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gridbagcons.gridx=0;
        gridbagcons.gridy=2;

        panel.add(buttonThree,gridbagcons); //INSTRUCTIONS
        // JButton icon details 
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);


        buttonTwo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonTwo.setContentAreaFilled(false);


        buttonThree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonThree.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        return panel;
        }
}
```

JWindow class :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class mainWindow {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                windowmain gui = new windowmain ();
                gui.window();
            } 

         public JWindow Window() throws IOException {

             MainWindow passme = new MainMenu();
             JComponent panel2 = passme.mainPanel();

             JWindow window = new JWindow("Lohn Jocke and the Quest for Qualia"); //Had to set window to final for the action listener
             window.add(panel2);
             window.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel2 );
             window.setSize(860,500);
             window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
             window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JWindow.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             window.setResizable(false);
             window.setVisible(true);

             return window;
         }

}
```

This class contains the panel that I want to be switched out in the first class :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class thewindow {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                thewindow gui = new thewindow ();
                gui.Window();
            } 

         public JWindow Window() throws IOException {

             MainMenu passme = new MainMenu();
             JComponent window = return.mainPanel();

             JWindow window = new JWindow("Lohn Jocke and the Quest for Qualia"); //Had to set window to final for the action listener
             window.add(panel2);
             window.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel2 );
             window.setSize(860,500);
             window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
             window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JWindow.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             window.setResizable(false);
             window.setVisible(true);

             return window;
         }

}
```

Again, thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), for this thingy ? One related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349137/1057230) :-) Moreover, why the use of thingy like, `final JComponent panel = new JLabel(...)`, making code hard to read, creating a `JLabel` and calling it `panel` :-)

Comment: I was told that GridBagLayout is the most versatile so I started learning it, but i'll definately look into CardLayout now and name my variables more appropriately, thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Icy100 : `GridBagLayout` is no doubt, one of the best `Layout Manager` provided by `Swing`. You can use `Nested Layout`, in the sense, that the base will use `CardLayout` and it will simply replace new `View` with the previous one, though each `View` will have it's own `Layout` like `GridBagLayout` to display it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Added that to my frame class, still getting nothing :/.. Thank you anyway though!

Comment: Since JDK5 you don't need to use getContentPane(). The frame's add method will add components to the content pane.