# Clicking from one frame to another while reading textfields

Tags: java, swing, textfield

I am quite new to Java, having the following question:

I want my Swing Applications users to put in various textfields in some frames.
That should happen like this:
When the application is started, a frame opens with some textfields and a submit button.
The submit  button sends the textfields data to the main method and closes the active frame.
Then a new frame opens with some more textfields and a submit button and so on.

How can I implement this in Java?
I understood that building multiple frames is not best practice, but what is the alternative?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [I understood that building multiple frames is not best practice, but what is the alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet oh that is best answer xD i should remove my answer

Answer (score 2):

> How can I implement this in Java? I understood that building multiple
>   frames is not best practice, but what is the alternative?

IMO the best alternative in your case is to have only a window (probably a JFrame), and using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between (probably) panels when an action happens. Also read [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice?lq=1)

Besides official tutorials that have examples, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349137/2415194) provide a commented example how to use CardLayout

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information with me, the example about CardLayout really got things going..

Comment: @user3328437 consider accepting the answer with the green check if it was helpful.